# Find number of function executions during tests

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I have a project with ~ 4000 unit tests that take a lot of time to execute.

I want to improve execution time by improving the most used and the most time consuming methods.

**How to find them?**

Comment: You can try to use a profiler tool.

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at your longest running tests (most frameworks will let you know how long individual tests take to run) then check these to make sure you've got any mocks setup correctly.  It's also worth considering that improving methods because they're hit a lot by your tests won't necessarily give what most people care about which is real world performance improvements since your code usage for testing is likely to be different than that for a typical live scenario.

Comment: I have about 10 tests running 1-2 seconds and 3000 about 100 ms, so making changes to top 10 time unit test make small difference, compared to general time.